# kendo ui - web tab-strip and grid responsive, how?

Tags: css, kendo-ui, responsive-design, media-queries, kendo-dataviz

I've used Kendo UI Web Tabstrip and Grid in my application. I am not using Twitter bootstrap for responsiveness. I am using media queries. As given in [Kendo documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/using-kendo-in-responsive-web-pages) I tried with `resize()` to make the tabstrip and grid responsive. But it didn't work. 
Please find this screenshot of tabstrip and grid taken for iPhone 5 Portrait mode.

[image: kendo ui grid iphone 5]

[image: kendo ui tabstrip iphone 5]

I also tried to modify classes `.k-tabstrip .k-content` in media query but it didn't work.

**How do I make tabstrip and grid responsive using media queries ???**

Comment: Experts, any update on this ???

Comment: This is a major drawback with kendo ui. All components should be responsive.